# Convert 9999999999999999999999.001 to "9999999999999999999999.001" in ruby

Tags: ruby

How to convert 9999999999999999999999.001 to "9999999999999999999999.001" in ruby

I have tried

```
>> 9999999999999999999999.001.to_s
=> "1.0e+22"

>> "%f" % 9999999999999999999999.001
=> "10000000000000000000000.000000"
```

Comment: Are you sure the literal `9999999999999999999999.001` is actually `9999999999999999999999.001`? Those look like more significant digits than what `double` can represent. So if ruby uses `double` for its numbers, this can't work. So I doubt that the conversion to string causes these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that. The reason is simple: from the very beginning the value of the number is not going to be exactly `9999999999999999999999.001`. Floats will have just 15 digits of precision.

However, you can use other type to achieve what you want:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
a = BigDecimal("9999999999999999999999.001")
a.to_s("F")
>> "9999999999999999999999.001"
```

For `BigDecimal` the precision is extended with the requests of bigger real numbers - no restrictions are applied.

Float is faster in calculations, because its meant to use the FPU of the processor directly, but because of that comes the restriction in the precision.

**EDIT** Especially for @izomorphius and his argument, just a very short code sample:

```
a = "34.101"
b = BigDecimal(a.to_s)
c = b ** 15
c.to_s("F")
>>> 98063348952510709441484.183684987951811295085234607613193907150561501
```

Now tell me how otherwise you get the last string?

Answer (score 2):

Truth is you can't. The number you write is 22 digits and floats in ruby have only 15 digits precision. So when you use this variable already part of its value is kind of "lost" as it is of the class Float.

Answer (score 2):

Use `BigDecimal` from the standard library.

```
1.8.7 :005 > require 'bigdecimal'
 => true 
1.8.7 :006 > BigDecimal('9999999999999999999999.001')
 => #<BigDecimal:7fe0cbcead70,'0.9999999999 9999999999 99001E22',36(36)> 
1.8.7 :007 > BigDecimal('9999999999999999999999.001').to_s
 => "0.9999999999999999999999001E22"
```

Of course, this example only shows that BigDecimal can handle numbers that big. Wherever you're initially getting your `9999999999999999999999.001` number from needs to get it into `BigDecimal` as soon as it's calculated / inputted.

Comment: You realize you use the string `9999999999999999999999.001` to get the  string `9999999999999999999999.001` the Op was interested into converting the value to a string, if you already have the string to initialize BigDecimal, he wouldn't have the problem in the first place.